# Why can't I call the variable I created in Context? How to call a variable with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Why can't I call the variable I created in Context?

This is the context file:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const GamesContext = createContext();

function Provider ({childern}) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

    const value = {
        count,
        increment: () => {
            setCount(count + 1);
        },
    };
    
    return <GamesContext.Provider value={value}>
        {childern}
    </GamesContext.Provider>
}

export default GamesContext;
export {Provider};
export const value = createContext(Provider);
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';
import {value} from "./context/games";
import GamesContext from "./context/games";

const el = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);

root.render(
<GamesContext.Provider value ={value}>
    <App />
</GamesContext.Provider>
);
```

and lastly here's where I called the variable {value}:

```
import GameShow from "./GameShow";
import { useContext } from "react";
import GamesContext from "../context/games";

function GameList ({games, onDelete, onEdit}) {
    const {count, increment} = useContext(GamesContext);
    ...
    });

    return <div className="book-list">
        {renderedGames}
        {count}
        <button onClick={increment}>Click</button>
    </div>

};
```

Everything works perfectly, the rendered objects and the button etc. but I can't see the value variables and I get no errors in the console.

I used to get various console errors so I tried different methods of exporting context and that got rid of the errors but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the exported `Provider` to wrap the `App` component. `createContext(Provider)` doesn't make much sense.

`context/games.js`:

```
export function Provider ({children}) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

    const value = {
        count,
        increment: () => {
            setCount(count + 1);
        },
    };
    
    return <GamesContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
    </GamesContext.Provider>
}
export default GamesContext;
```

`index.js`:

```
import {Provider} from "./context/games";
// ...
root.render(
  <Provider>
      <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: I tried this and I get no errors whatsoever but all I see is a blank page when I run it, maybe my browser is the issue?

Comment: @abdulRAHMAN The code in my answer has been tested and it does work. Note, however, that I corrected the misspelling of `children` as `childern` in `Provider` (which may be causing your issue).

Comment: THANK YOU! that solved it lol, I'll make sure to double check the spelling next time